# Bing map rotation in windows phone pivot

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml

I have a trouble when try to rotate MapBase. As far as I didn't find a way to rotate content inside map(i mean tiles). I made a rotation transform with map itself and put it in square to emulate a rectangual viewport.
The problem is the map corner flows over corner of square while rotating and what worst it moves over pivot items titles and I don't know how to bring it to the bottom.
Is there any workaround of that? Or may be other way to rotate the map content?

UPDATE
XAML CODE
here is my code

```
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <!--Pivot Control-->
    <controls:Pivot Title="MY APPLICATION">
        <!--Pivot item one-->
        <controls:PivotItem Header="first">
            <Grid d:LayoutOverrides="Height" Margin="-44,-30,44,30">
                <Microsoft_Phone_Controls_Maps:Map Margin="-18,-72,2,76" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" UseLayoutRounding="False" d:LayoutRounding="Auto">
                    <Microsoft_Phone_Controls_Maps:Map.RenderTransform>
                        <CompositeTransform Rotation="36.01"/>
                    </Microsoft_Phone_Controls_Maps:Map.RenderTransform>
                </Microsoft_Phone_Controls_Maps:Map>
                <Rectangle Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Height="54" Margin="-14,-42,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

            </Grid>
        </controls:PivotItem>

        <!--Pivot item two-->
        <controls:PivotItem Header="second">

        </controls:PivotItem>
    </controls:Pivot>
</Grid>
```

In  the example  is on the top of map, but map is on the top of Pivot headers and even application title is on the back of map corner...

Answer (score 0):

And If you Load another page in "Paysage Orientation" when you rotate your phone ? (It's maybe a temporaly solution... ) but you want to reaload your map with good dimension.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to use a Map Control inside a Pivot if gesture interaction is enabled.

> Don’t use Slider, ToggleButton, or Map controls in a Pivot control. Don’t use controls that can pan or scroll inside a Pivot control. For example, if you put a Map control inside a Pivot control it might be difficult to use the Pivot control. The gesture input gets confused. The solution is to navigate to a subpage with controls that require gesture input. You can place a map in a pivot page as long as the map isn’t enabled for gesture interaction. You could overlay a button that would activate the map. Pressing the button would actually navigate to a separate page with just the Map control on it. The user could then press the Back button to go back to the Pivot control.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/design/hh202919%28v=vs.105%29.aspx